# Sum over variable size windows defined by custom boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

I can solve this problem using a loop structure, so I am specifically wondering whether there is any numpy/vectorized method of accomplishing this.

I have two arrays of values of the same length, e.g.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [False, True, True, False, False, True]
```

I would like to sum all the elements in `a` which correspond to each window of "true" positions in `b` and add them to the immediately preceding "false" values (again in `a`).  So to complete the example I gave I would like to get the output

```
c = [6,4,11]
```

In this case we get:
6 (sum of 1,2,3 from the sequence `[False, True, True,` in `b`), 4 (no "True" positions immediately following in `b`) , 11 (from `False, True` in b).

I realize that may be hard to follow, so please let me know if another example/more explanation would be helpful.

Comment: `np.add.reduceat(a,np.flatnonzero(b==0))` seems to be working. Could you show how would you do with a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will piggyback on @Divakar's comment. It is a great idea to use `np.add.reduceat()`. However, it seems to me that @Divakar's treatment of indices is too simplistic for this problem and a more complicated analysis is required. I think the following may produce what you are looking for:

```
idx = np.insert(
    np.flatnonzero(
        np.ediff1d(np.pad(b.astype(np.int), 1, 'constant', constant_values=0)) == -1
    ), 0, 0
)
wsum = np.add.reduceat(np.append(a, 0), idx)[:-1]
```

## Test

With

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 11)
>>> b = np.array([True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False, True])
```

I get:

```
>>> print(wsum)
[ 3  7 18 27]
```